# sort function changes the copy and the original

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this code and it changes the original array arr even when I copy it to a variable I named copy.
The data(arr) is supplied by codewars

```
cutIt(["codewars","javascript","java"])
function cutIt(arr){
  //coding here...
  //step 1 go through array and find the shortest
  // sort string by length
  // make copy of arr not to affect it
  let copy = arr;
  console.log(copy);
 //[ 'codewars', 'javascript', 'java' ]
  let sorted = copy.sort(function (a,b) {
   return a.length - b.length;

  })

  console.log(arr);
  //[ 'java', 'codewars', 'javascript' ]
}
```

I did not explicitly change the array arr in the code but the output shows it has been changed? I thought by making a copy of it and sorting the copy it would not affect arr?

Comment: The sort() method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the array. You are not making a copy of the array, only a copy of the reference. [Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort)

Comment: Both variables reference the same array, hence why the original change, try making a new array that's contains the same ements as the original.

Comment: Thanks I think i have got a better understanding a bit like a second pointer to the same variable...

Answer (score 3):

```
// make copy of arr not to affect it
let copy = arr;
```

That's not actually true; you just made a second variable refer to the same array instance.

You can create an actual copy by calling `arr.slice()`.

Comment: thanks i did not know i was referring to the same memory location. I this true for more simple types, like: let i = 10;  let x = i i =i + 1 now i = 10 but x = 11..I appreciate your help you solved the problem with the slice

Answer (score 0):

Array is not a primitive data type. At best they're variants of objects. And objects pass by reference and not a value which is worthy of note. That said, there're couple of ways to make a deep clone of an array if that's the intent.

1) **Vanilla JS:**

```
E.g

const newArraryCopy = <Your array>.slice();
```

2) **Lodash:**

```
E.g

var array = [{},{},{}];

var copy = _.map(array, _.clone);
```

Comment: The second method is beyond me at the moment..var array = [{},{},{}];

var copy = _.map(array, _.clone); I do not understand _.map etc, but thanks